# WHERE + AND query doesn't work SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Im trying to select some values from my table, but it returns 0 rows. If I comment one of clauses - it works, but when I add "and" it doesnt.

Here is my code

```
cursor = mValtoneDB.mDataBase.rawQuery("select activity.name as name, activity._id as id " +
            "from activity inner join discipline " +
            "on discipline._id = activity.disciplineId " +
            "inner join user_discipline_lt " +
            "on discipline._id = user_discipline_lt.disciplineId "
            + "where" +
                    " user_discipline_lt.userId=? " +
                    "and" +
                    " discipline._id=?"
            , new String[] { Integer.toString(userId), Integer.toString(disciplineId) }
```

I dont know what to do :\

As db is filling randomly I logged a lot(too much output) here is everything about discipline with id 3 :

```
    01-05 04:39:38.330    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 1
    01-05 04:39:38.330    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 2
    01-05 04:39:38.330    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 5
    01-05 04:39:38.330    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 6
    01-05 04:39:38.330    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 7
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 9
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 10
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 16
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 18
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 19
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 20
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 22
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 23
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 24
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 1
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 2
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 5
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 6
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 7
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 9
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 10
    01-05 04:39:38.335    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 16
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 18
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 19
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 20
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 22
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 23
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 24
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 1
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 2
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 5
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 6
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 7
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 9
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 10
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 16
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 18
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 19
    01-05 04:39:38.340    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 20
    01-05 04:39:38.345    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 22
    01-05 04:39:38.345    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 23
    01-05 04:39:38.345    1836-1836/cullycross.cursed D/cursors info:﹕ discipline id 3 user id 24
```

Comment: Do you have an example of rows that you believe should have generated a result?

Comment: Yes, if change where clause to:
    "where" +
          /*" user_discipline_lt.userId=? " +
          "and" +*/
          " discipline._id=?"

It works, but it shows not what I want

Comment: @Amadan yes i have, im logging them, while i input them

Comment: Can you provide an example? Which data does your database has and which values do you pass for `userId` and `disciplineId`?

Comment: I meant, can you *show us* an example of rows that you believe should have generated a result? (edit them into the question) :)

Comment: @Tom its my students work, so I dont have true values(I input new random ones every time I launch app, I dont know how to show you). Last time I passed: 01-05 04:11:01.020  31197-31197/cullycross.cursed D/INTENTS EXTRA﹕ User id: 34 Discipline id: 4

Comment: @Amadan wait, I have to log them before. I random them every time I start this app.

Comment: If you can't show us the data, how can we possibly tell you why it's not being selected?

Comment: The point is, you should log the contents of the tables in sufficient detail that you can manually deduct whether the rows fitting your criteria actually exist or not. Or you can try to copy the SQLite database back to your PC, so you can inspect it using the SQLite client, and have a real foundation for testing your queries.

Comment: @Amadan i edited topic

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is correct. Remove your "and" clause and observes the results. Check that you have at least one row where your discipline._id is as expected.

Comment: I've edited topic, its half of the log(copied everything with disciplineId = 3). This is everything without any where clause about discipline 3

Comment: Ok, what values are you passing in for disciplineId and userId when the result is 0 rows? I assume you are passing in "3" for discipline. What value are you passing for user?

Comment: I input new user "admin" - userid - 1, discipline Id - the row, i click. I log that numbers also.

Comment: Before you call your SQL statement above log `new String[] { Integer.toString(userId), Integer.toString(disciplineId) }` and see if the the two values are as you expected. Your disciplineId might not be getting to the assigned to the variable correctly.